# AJAX: how to get back the "this" of the object

Tags: jquery

Here's my problem, that I'm trying to make it as short as possible:

```
function Game()

    this.clickStartGame = function() {
        $('#xxx').fadeOut(function() {
            console.log(this);
            /* how to call this.showInformation() from here? */
        });
    };

    this.showInformation = function () {
        /* blabbla */
    }
}

var m = new Game();
m.clickStartGame();
```

How to call `this.showInformation()` when the `fadeOut()` event is finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is by default inside the fadeOut() handler `this` will refer to the element which was faded out.

One easy solution is to use a closure variable and use it to call the method

```
function Game() {

    this.clickStartGame = function () {
        var self = this;
        $('#xxx').fadeOut(function () {
            console.log(self);
            /* how to call self.showInformation() from here? */
        });
    };

    this.showInformation = function () {
        /* blabbla */
    }
}
```

---

Another is to use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)/[Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to pass a custom execution context to the fadeOut() callback like

```
function Game() {

    this.clickStartGame = function () {
        $('#xxx').fadeOut($.proxy(function () {
            console.log(this);
            /* how to call this.showInformation() from here? */
        }, this));
    };

    this.showInformation = function () {
        /* blabbla */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Game()

    var gameObj = this;

    this.clickStartGame = function() {
        $('#xxx').fadeOut(function() {
            console.log(this);
            gameObj.showInformation();
            /* how to call this.showInformation() from here? */
        });
    };

    this.showInformation = function () {
        /* blabbla */
    }
}
```

Would this work?

Comment: I want to make it as generic as possible... maybe there's a more generic way of handling this?